# sublime text unsaved files on closing the window

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I want to know what exactly happens when I close the entire window(like `alt-f4`) and it does not ask me for a file name to save the file with. And surprisingly, on reopening everything reopens as it is. How can I know where the buffer is being saved?

Comment: It keeps buffer for the open file.Note that multiple views may refer to the same buffer, but they have their own unique selection and geometry.

Comment: yes, where does it save the buffer(since it is able to reopen exactly in the same state, it must save it somewhere)?

Comment: you can move your question to Super User, /home/user/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/ can get file location from here